# Symfony and Doctrine DQL query builder: how to use multiple setParameters inside if condition checks?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, dql

Using Symfony and Doctrine with the DQL query builder, I need to optionally add some WHERE conditions with parameters, with some if condition checks.

Pseudo code example:

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$qb = $qb
    ->select('SOMETHING')
    ->from('SOMEWHERE')
    ->where('SOME CONDITIONS');


if ( SOME CHECK ) {
    $qb
        ->andWhere('field1 = :field1')
        ->andWhere('field2 = :field2')
        ->setParameters([
            'field1' => $myFieldValue1,
            'field2' => $myFieldValue2,
        ]);
} else {
    $qb
        ->andWhere('field1 = :field1')
        ->setParameters([
            'field1' => $myOtherFieldValue1,
        ]);
}
```

Getting errors like:

> Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
>
> Too few parameters: the query defines X parameters but you only bound Y
>
> Too many parameters: the query defines X parameters and you bound Y

Comment: in the where conditions set out of the if statement how do you pass the field value? probably you override the first setparameter.

Comment: that was just an example, see my answer below

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the cleanest solution to this problem I've found so far, is to wrap all the parameters inside an array and then calling only once the `setParameters()` method, checking if there is at least one parameter to set:

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$qb = $qb
    ->select('SOMETHING')
    ->from('SOMEWHERE')
    ->where('SOME CONDITIONS')

$parameters = [];

if ( SOME CHECK ) {
    $qb
        ->andWhere('field1 = :field1')
        ->andWhere('field2 = :field2');

    $parameters['field1'] = $myFieldValue1;
    $parameters['field2'] = $myFieldValue2;

} else {
    $qb->andWhere('field1 = :field1');
    $parameters['field1'] = $myOtherFieldValue1;
}

if (count($parameters)) {
    $qb->setParameters($parameters);
}
```

Comment: Your original code looks like it should work.  I do it all the time except I use setParameter instead of setParameters.  Might try using individual setParameter calls.  It's a shame to have to break up the organization.

Answer (score 2):

You can set parameters one by one:

```
$qb
    ->setParameter('field1', $value1)
    ->setParameter('field2', $value2);
```

This way you'll be sure that you don't override other params with `setParameters`.

Comment: I think it's better solution than the accepted.